# Android value of arraylist out of method

Tags: android

I have this code created with Volley and JSON:

```
public List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

public List<String> mostraDati(){

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, DatiNet.MostraDati, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            System.out.println(response.toString());
            try {
                System.out.println("fin qui ci siamo");
                JSONArray utenti = response.getJSONArray("utenti");

                List<String> resTemp = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (int i = 0; i < utenti.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject student = utenti.getJSONObject(i);

                    String nome = student.getString("nome");
                    String cognome = student.getString("cognome");
                    String numero = student.getString("numero");
                    String email = student.getString("email");

                    resTemp.add(nome + " " + cognome + " " + email);

                }

                result = resTemp;

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.append(error.getMessage());

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    System.out.println(result.toString());

    return result;
}
```

It works well but the return is always null "[]". How to solve the problem?
I think the problem is to port the value out of the method of jsonObjectRequest.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you get response?

Comment: yes the method works but i can't return

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Volley, json and php connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058341/volley-json-and-php-connection)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your code to add one `arrayList` value to another `arrayList`.

Change

```
result = resTemp;
```

to

```
result.addAll(resTemp);
```

Comment: Are you setting arrayList directly to TextView? Can you show your full code?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c86cf4a52b830ee542b0                   https://gist.github.com/anonymous/07ab7f02f73250917c97